# DirectDraw get procedure address using GetProcAddress

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, directx, directdraw

As stated in the documentation for the [IDirectDraw7::SetCooperativeLevel method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg426155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it states

> You must use LoadLibrary to explicitly link to Ddraw.dll and then use GetProcAddress to access the SetCooperativeLevel method.

in the remarks. However when I attempt to do so (code below), it fails to work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
typedef HRESULT (*pSetCooperativeLevelFunc)(HWND, DWORD);
HMODULE ddrawLib = LoadLibrary(L"ddraw.dll");
pSetCooperativeLevelFunc SCL = (pSetCooperativeLevelFunc) GetProcAddress(
                                 ddrawLib,
                                 "SetCooperativeLevel"
                                 );

if (SCL == NULL) {
    // this happens
    int error = GetLastError(); // 127 (ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND)
    printf("Error getting SetCooperativeLevel function address: %i", error);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exported `SetCooperativeLevel` function in ddraw.dll. Use `DUMPBIN` utility and check it yourself. You can get `DirectDrawCreate`/`DirectDrawCreateEx` and similar functions using `GetProcAddress`, but you can't extract individual methods of COM object.

Article is quite ridiculous and doesn't make sense. Perhaps it was supposed to tell you to get `DirectDrawCreate` from ddraw.dll or something like that, but there's little reason to do that.

Link with `ddraw.lib`, call `DirectDrawCreate` and access methods provided by IDirectDraw7 interface.

P.S. If you aren't familiar with dumpbin, I'd suggest to learn at least basic usage of this utility.

Comment: I want to meet the people who write some of these MSDN articles. You got unlucky with the fact that there are no comments at the bottom of it explaining the situation.

Comment: That's what i thought too, i'll try to learn how to use `DUMPBIN`, thanks.

Comment: @chris: "people who write some of these MSDN articles." It is actually quite strange. I have impression that roughly 5..7 years ago documentation from MSDN was very good, but then "something" happened, and things started to deteriorate quickly. Now the whole thing is a mess that is hard to navigate and requires google search to get decent results, which is a pity.

Comment: You can't GetProcAddress for a COM interface's method. But it's worth noting that in recente DX (from 9 on) there's no ddraw.lib any more, so you need to use GetProcAddress to call the functions that ddraw.dll exports, like DirectDrawCreate etc. etc. It's a MSDN documentation bug, they added the remark to every DDraw method.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a documentation bug.  It's been a long time since I used DirectDraw7, but I don't recall having to load it dynamically.  It was just a method of the IDirectDraw7 interface and called like any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Since DX9, ddraw.lib was completely removed from the SDK, so you need to call LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress to call DirectDrawCreate or DirectDrawEnumerate. Unfortunately MSDN got it wrong, and added the GetProcAddress remark to EVERY DirectDraw function, even the COM interfaces' methods.